# Can I use the Sharing product to upload a photo automatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

The test setup for my Facebook application's backend  creates some Facebook test users and uploads a photo for each one.

Now the setup fails with an error like this:

```
(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions
```

The test code makes a post request to the 'me/photos' method using the test user's access token.

On 2018-08-01 Facebook removed the `publish_actions` permission from the Graph API. This change appears to make obsolete the documentation for [uploading photos using the Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads/).

Facebook recommends using the [Sharing product](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) instead, but doesn't seem to have any example of how to use it to replace this automated process.

Is it possible to automate this process using the Sharing product?

Comment: No it is not possible to share automatically. It wasn't allowed before anyway.

Comment: Thanks @WizKid. You could make that an answer and resolve this. Just to clarify, I don't really care about automating the "sharing", it's the photo upload that really interests me. Maybe that's for another question.

Comment: uploading a photo or sharing a message are pretty much the same things when it comes to autoposting: it was not allowed and still is not. and it is not possible anymore anyway.

Comment: There is no way to automate sharing via the dialogs. The user has to interact with them manually to trigger sharing.